# carrierwave double key in serializable_hash

Tags: serialization, rails-activerecord, carrierwave, jsonserializer

I have a user model which mount a carrierwave uploader for a field called profile_img. code folows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :profile_img, ProfileUploader
end
```

the output of profile_img field is like this:

```
"profile_img": {
            "url": "https://halo-img-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/profile_img/1000/cola_iOS2_512_dribbble2.png",
            "thumb": {
                "url": "https://halo-img-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/profile_img/1000/thumb_cola_iOS2_512_dribbble2.png"
            },
            "medium": {
                "url": "https://halo-img-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/profile_img/1000/medium_cola_iOS2_512_dribbble2.png"
            }
        }
```

When I try to customize serialize hash by simply calling super,

```
def serializable_hash(options = {})
    super(options)
end
```

the profile_image field key get duplicated

```
"profile_img": {
        "profile_img": {  #### duplicate here
            "url": "https://halo-img-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/profile_img/1000/cola_iOS2_512_dribbble2.png",
            "thumb": {
                "url": "https://halo-img-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/profile_img/1000/thumb_cola_iOS2_512_dribbble2.png"
            },
            "medium": {
                "url": "https://halo-img-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/profile_img/1000/medium_cola_iOS2_512_dribbble2.png"
            }
        }
    },
```

I suspect this issue rooted from carrierwave serialize method, but can not find a solution on it.

#### Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

solution for:

1. **jBuilder**

   ```
   json.profile_img @user.profile_img.serializable_hash
   ```
2. **ActiveModelSerializer**

   ```
   # attributes
   def profile_img
     object.profile_img.serializable_hash
   end
   ```